# Can't pass children with props using React.cloneElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I got this error

```
invariant.js:42 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid
```

doing this

```
const ListWrap = ({ children, onChange }) => {
  return <div>{React.cloneElement(children, { onChange })}</div>
}
```

But no issue when I do

```
const ListWrap = ({ children }) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>
}
```

But I can't pass the props by merely doing `return <div>{children}</div>`. Any clue what went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`React.cloneElement` takes a single child. This should fix it:

```
const ListWrap = ({ children, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div>
    {React.Children.map(children, child => React.cloneElement(child, { onChange }))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @JennyTeng the methods are documented in https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html. If you have the time check out the "compound components" pattern, there is a video of Ryan Florence explaining it in detail

Comment: what if children isn't an array but only a single child?? you can't use map on that then

Comment: @OZZIE that's what `React.Children` is for. It's meant to handle every shape the children data structure takes

Comment: If children is only one element you get stuck with `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

works when it's multiple elements, in my case it should always be 1 element.. Using React 17.0.2

Comment: @OZZIE you can probably just use `React.cloneElement` in that case, good catch though. This answer is from 2018, so there is the possibility that this implementation has changed